# How to enable TLS in a Java project?

Tags: java, ssl

I developed an application working with TCP sockets. Now I would like it to work with a TLS connection.

I searched some resources for now 2 days but there is nothing that looks like a tutorial on how to implement TLS.

Here is what I understood with what I have to do :

- I have to import my root CA in my *keystore*.
- I have to import some others certificates in my *keystore* / *truststore*.

I can't find a clear sample of code that explain really what to do.

Can you please help me with some client/server example or other helpful tutorial?
(I already tried to search "TLS java", "TLS Java example", "TLS Java tutorial" etc. But I could not find anything satisfying.)

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Is your question specifically about TLS (as opposed to SSL)? Are you trying to implement SSL/TLS yourself or are you willing to enabled what's already in the JSSE for your application?

Comment: I would like to implement what is already in the JSSE.

Comment: Just to clarify, presumably, by this you mean *use* what's already in the JSSE, not *re-implement* what's in the JSSE?

Comment: I mean **use** what's in JSSE.

Comment: You need to read the JSSE Reference Guide. Hard to believe you didn't turn that up in two days of searching. It's part of the Javadoc after all, should have been the first place you looked.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is two way to achieve this.

The easiest lies in Java protocol support and the `URL` object.

But since I think you already figured out that `new URL("https://www.google.com").openStream()` gives you a clear text input stream while dealing with all the TLS/SSL stuff for you, I'll go for the "hard" way :)

Just before I'll answer your other question: importing a CA.
CA certificates are located in your Java home at either of theses locations:

- `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` (JRE)
- `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` (JDK; notice the 'jre' just
  after the Java home)

For both the default password is "changeit".

To list its content you can use the `keytool` command:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

To add a new cert just use the `-import` subcommand instead of `-list`.

So now let's go for the "hard" way (client code):

```
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

...
String host = "www.google.com";
int port = 443;

SocketFactory basicSocketFactory = SocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket s = basicSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
// s is a TCP socket

SSLSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
s = tlsSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, true);
// s is now a TLS socket over TCP
```

It's as simple as that.

If you need a server socket the code is almost the same, you just have to exchange `SocketFactory` for `ServerSocketFactory` and `SSLSocketFactory` for `SSLServerSocketFactory`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the JRE7 there is no file or folder named truststore. Should I create one or is this done with Keytool ?

Comment: Sorry Kaijiro, I wrote my answer from memory, the file name is `cacerts` not -truststore- I'll correct my answer

Comment: Why create the plaintext  socket first? No need for that complication. See the JSSE Reference Guide as suggested.

Comment: @user207421 My answer has two parts : the easy way with `URL` and the complex one with sockets. I shown the socket approach as it's required for some exotic proprietary protocols that work the same way as SMTP+STARTTLS : first start a clear text socket, exchange some data and then negociate TLS. If the protocol is not supported by Java, you need to do it by hand